# Prove that $E_1E_2= E_2E_1 = E_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem about projections I don't understand, Can somebody help me please?

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$ and let $E_1$ and $E_2$ are projections of V with image $R_1$ and $R_2$ and nullspaces $N_1$ and $N_2$  respectively. Suposse that $R_2\subset{R_1}$ and $N_1\subset{N_2}$ Prove that $E_1E_2= E_2E_1 = E_2$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you start by defining, as you understand it, what a projection onto a subspace is?  Once you have that you can at least try to apply it.

Comment: Hint: $V=R_1\oplus N_1=R_2\oplus R_1\cap N_2\oplus N_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that if $p$ is a projection and if $x\in \mathrm{Im}(p)$ then $p(x)=x$ and recall that $x-p(x)\in \ker(p)$

We have $E_2(x)\in R_2\subset R_1$ so $E_1(E_2(x))=E_2(x)$, moreover $x-E_1(x)\in N_1\subset N_2$ so $E_2(x-E_1(x))=0$ so $E_2(E_1(x))=E_2(x)$ and we conclude.

Comment: You're welcome.